# AutoIT, print Array output to text file

Tags: arrays, string, ascii, autoit

This is my first ever post on Stackoverflow! any help would be much appreciated.

Im an AutoIT beginner and trying to create a script that takes a string, converts it to ASCII and saves it in an array using **StringToASCIIArray**

What i would like to achieve is that, i need the output to be printed in a text file, so i can copy it for later use.

Ive tried using **ConsoleWrite** Function, the characters get printed just as i expect them to be, however it would nice if someone could point me out in the right direction to have them printed in a new text file or something. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3> 

Test()

Func Test()
; Convert the string to an ASCII array.
Local $aArray = StringToASCIIArray("Hi, this is a new string")
Local $sizeArr = UBound($aArray)

For $i = 0 to $sizeArr - 1
    ConsoleWrite("Chr(" & $aArray[$i] & ")" & " & ")    ; need this output     in a new variable?
Next

;Run("notepad.exe")
;WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
;Send($aNewArray)
EndFunc
```

**Update**
I managed to do it by creating a console application that takes an input string, converts the input to ascii and displays the formated output on the console. I can simply copy the output from there on....Not the best solution though, but it works :)

Code::

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

myexample()

Func myexample()

 Local $sInput
 While True
    $sInput &= ConsoleRead()
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    Sleep(25)
WEnd

Local $aArray = StringToASCIIArray($sInput)     ; store string to array
 Local $sizeArr = UBound($aArray)       ; Get array size

For $i = 0 to $sizeArr - 1               ;For each element of array Do:
ConsoleWrite("Chr(" & $aArray[$i] & ")" & " & ") ;write to console ascii in Chr() 
Next

EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello ist this what you want?

```
;~ string = example string :: output = Chr(101) & Chr(120) & Chr(97) & Chr(109) & Chr(112) & Chr(108) & Chr(101) & Chr(32) & Chr(115) & Chr(116) & Chr(114) & Chr(105) & Chr(110) & Chr(103)

Global $re = Test('example string')
ConsoleWrite($re & @CRLF)
FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\output.txt', $re)
ShellExecute(@ScriptDir & '\output.txt')

Func Test($str)
    ; Convert the string to an ASCII array.
    Local $aArray = StringToASCIIArray($str)
    Local $s = ''

    For $i = 0 To UBound($aArray) - 1
;~      ConsoleWrite("Chr(" & $aArray[$i] & ")" & " & ") ; need this output     in a new variable?
        $s &= "Chr(" & $aArray[$i] & ") & "
    Next
    $s = StringTrimRight($s, 3) ; delete the last "blank & blank"
    Return $s
EndFunc   ;==>Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `_FileWriteFromArray` to get your file.

Why do you put the string in an array at all? Convert it and just use `FileWrite`

Comment: thanks, the reason why the string goes in the array is because of the StringToASCIIArray function, couldnt find anything else to use. Ive read about the _FileWriteFromArray and the thing is, i need the output in a particular format. i.e The output of the FOR loop ---> new text file

Comment: Could you please provide an example. String you have and how it should looklike when it is saved in a file.

Comment: string = example string ::
output = Chr(101) & Chr(120) & Chr(97) & Chr(109) & Chr(112) & Chr(108) & Chr(101) & Chr(32) & Chr(115) & Chr(116) & Chr(114) & Chr(105) & Chr(110) & Chr(103)

Answer (score 0):

```
For $i = 0 to $sizeArr - 1
    ConsoleWrite("Chr(" & $aArray[$i] & ")" & " & ")
    FileWrite("test.txt", $aArray[$i] & @CRLF)
Next
```

Comment: Nah, doesnt work that way. Its saving the elements of the array to the file without formating them the way i want them to be....the output i want needs to be this way : **Chr(104) & Chr(116) & Chr(116) & Chr(112)*** . Thanks for the help anyway!